# Trouble with table and checkbox functionality

Tags: jquery

I have a table with listed checkboxes and a table header with a radio button. I am trying to make it to where a user must check the radio button in order to have a checkbox selected, if a checkbox is selected and no radio button, it gives an alert. also if the radio button is checked, at least 1 checkbox must be selected

I had this somewhat working but my function to check the table for checkboxes :checked also counts the checked for my radio button. 
Does anyone have an idea for a work around?

```
<Table id = 'mytable>
   <tr>
     <th>
       <input name="myradio" type="radio" id="myradio">
     </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <input name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/>
        <input name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"/>
        <input name="checkbox3" type="checkbox" id="checkbox3"/>
        <input name="checkbox4" type="checkbox" id="checkbox4"/>
     </td>
</table>
```

Here is an example of the table.

```
var mytable = $('#mytable').find(':checked').length;
var myradio = $('#myradio').is(':checked');

.....
if((mytable) && (!myradio)){
    alert("must select radio & checkbox");
  }
```

When the radio button is checked, it also  finds a check in the mytable variable which I cannot find a work around where I dont have to break up the table.

Comment: To find the checked checkboxes you can try `$('#mytable input[type=checkbox]').find(':checked')`

Comment: This isn't valid HTML

Comment: I think the correct short-tag for `input` is `<input />` and not `</input>`

Comment: Yea thats my fault, the page is formatted completely different this was just something i typed real quick as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your propose:

```
var mytable = $('#mytable input[type=checkbox]').find(':checked').length;
var myradio = $('#myradio').is(':checked');

if(mytable <= 0 && (!myradio)){
    alert("must select radio & checkbox");
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2ty32gk8/)**

Note: `.length` is returning `0` when no checked input is found.

**Reference**

[jQuery attribute-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: This seems to work, I'm still learning all the functionality with the selector. Thanks